# Meteor - How to Run Multiple Server Processes Simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

My Meteor app needs to run 13 separate server processes, each on a `setInterval`. Essentially, I am pinging 13 different external APIs for new data, and performing calculations on the response and storing the results in Mongo. Each process looks something like this:

```
Meteor.setInterval(function () {
  try {
    var response = Meteor.http.call("GET", <url>, {
      params: <params>,
      timeout: <timeout>
    });
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    // handle the response
    ...
  }
}, 10000);
```

Unfortunately, Meteor chokes up after only three of these interval functions are turned on and running side by side. I start getting `socket hangup` errors and `JS Allocation Failed` errors thrown in console. I presume this has something to do with Node's single-threading. Does anybody know what the solution is for this? I've looked long and hard... I'm really wondering if I have to split out the back-end from 1 Meteor app with 13 processes (which doesn't seem to run) to 13 Meteors (or Node.js apps), each with 1 process. Thanks!

Comment: What is Meteor.http.call?  See docs on [HTTP.call](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call).

Comment: You have "looked long and hard" and **found** what and **tried** what to solve this issue?

Comment: Meteor.http.call was the old way of making HTTP requests pre Meteor 1.0. Thanks for the link, I have updated my code. @Kyll I have found very little information on this topic, hence the post. As far as attempts, I am currently test-driving the new `meteorhacks: cluster` package since that may give Meteor access to multiple cores (https://github.com/meteorhacks/cluster#multi-core-support), but that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Try https://atmospherejs.com/vsivsi/job-collection

Benefits:

- Jobs can be added to a queue, and you have granular control over when they succeed or fail... failed jobs can easily be re-queued.
- It's automatically clustered against all of your Meteor processes that are tied to the same collection.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at this and post my results.

Answer (score 0):

Status update: a large part of the problem has to do with Node being single-threaded. I solved the CPU limitation problem by splitting out this monolithic Meteor app into 13 microservices Meteor apps, all connected to the same MongoDB replica set.

This way, all cores on the CPU are being utilized, rather than Meteor trying to handle all requests and processes on just one.